# This is my code.In this after checking values for matching direct else is printing. IF is not executing. why?

Tags: java

This is my code. In this after checking values for matching direct else is printing. IF is not executing. why?

```
{
    int index = 1;
    index = mapStringList(preparedStatement, index, eC1.getIy());

    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
        String eD = result.getString("code");
        logger.info("code:{}", eD);

        for (String values : eC1.getIy()) {
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(values) && values.matches(eD)) {
                eC.setBd(result.getString("bd"));
                eC.setCy(result.getString("cy"));
                al.add(eC);
            } else {
                logger.error("No matches found");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet the `if` is executing, but the condition does not evaluate true. Try a debugger. Also, I would not retrieve everything from the database if there is some criteria that should be matched; that is, **filter** in your query so you don't have to read rows you don't want.

Comment: i need to return bd and cy values from db.but it is checking the first value and second value is getting overridden by first one

Comment: Also use variable names that mean something

Answer (score 0):

it won't execute because you have a missing opening curly brace.

```
{
    int index = 1;
    index = mapStringList(preparedStatement, index, eC1.getIy());
    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
        String eD = result.getString("code");
        logger.info("code:{}", eD);

        for (String values : eC1.getIy()){
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(values) && values.matches(eD)) {
                eC.setBd(result.getString("bd"));
                eC.setCy(result.getString("cy"));
                al.add(eC);

            } else {
                logger.error("No matches found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where it is can you please tell?

Comment: after ` for (String values : eC1.getIy())`

Comment: Single line `for` loops are bad style (and arguably shouldn't have been added to Java), but they are perfectly legal.